# Why can't we decrement Data Pointer in ALP?

Tags: assembly, 8051

As we can just increment the data pointer in ALP:

```
INC DPTR;  //valid
```

But we cannot use:

```
DEC DPTR;  //invalid
```

Instead, we have to use:

```
DEC DPL;  //decrementing the lower nibble of Data Pointer
```

Question:

1. Why can we not decrement the Data Pointer?
2. If decrementing the Data Pointer is not allowed then how are we decrementing it's lower nibble?

Comment: 1. Who knows. That's just how they made the instruction set. 2. The same way as you would do with any other 16 bit quantity. You just don't get an efficient single instruction for it.

Comment: Is `dec dpl` really just the low *nibble* (4 bits), not the whole low byte?

Answer (score 1):

The solution in @syeedameen's answer can be improved, just a bit. Beside that, the code using SUBB A, #01 is actually wrong, because SUBB also subtracts the value in the carry flag, which is undefined.

Here a solution, four instructions only, 9 bytes code, that does NOT modify the ACC register or the flags in the PSW. It's decrementing the DPTR using DPH and DPL registers:

```
  INC  DPL                  ; inc / djnz as a jump-if != 0 without modifying yet
  DJNZ DPL, SkipDecDPH
  DEC  DPH                  ; decrement high half if low half will wrap
SkipDecDPH:
  DEC DPL
```

Answer (score 0):

The 8051 microcontroller was built like tha, the instruction for decrementing the 16-bit data pointer(DTPR) is not provided.

The only way to decrement the datapointer is to decrement the low and high byte separately.
I.e 
DEC DPL and DEC DPH although there are still a couple of other instructions involved in the decrementing.

Answer (score 0):

### 1. There is no such Instruction in MCS-51 ISA for decrement data pointer or (DPTR register)

### 2. To decrement the datapointer is to decrement the low and high byte separately. `DEC DPL` and `DEC DPH`

***PROCEDURE FOR DECREMENT DATAPOINTER***

first of all decrement dpl `DEC DPL` and check carry flag (because if `DPL` already contain 0x00 for example `DPTR = 0x4500`) if `C=1` decrement dph `DEC DPH` and move `'0xFF` into DPL register

***look at this subroutine***

```
MAIN_PROGRAM:
    .......
    .......
    CALL DEC_DPTR 
    ......





    ;DECREMENT DATA POINTER SUBROUITNE 
        DEC_DPTR:
            MOV A, DPL 
            SUBB A, #01 
            JNC SKIP_DEC_DPTR
            MOV A, #0XFF 
            DEC DPH 
        SKIP_DEC_DPTR:
            MOV DPL, A 
            RET
```